# Why the General Tab Currency Precision Setting affects the Number setting in Formats Tab

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

There is a setting in System Settings -> General Tab:

`Set the currency precision that is used for pricing throughout the system`

When I change and apply this setting (e.g. 4), it reflects the change in Formats -> Number (preview) also.

While I read that the **general tab currency precision setting only impacts pricing on products**, why it is reflecting the applied effect on Formats tab also?

Comment: can you please provide bit more info.

Comment: sorry, if I am not specific. What more info do you want, please?